# Is there a way to have a Session available right after declaring it (without reload of the page)

Tags: php, session

When I create a Session with `$_SESSION['test'] = "value";`, it will not directly be available but only after a reload of the page.

Can I achieve something like this without a reload?

```
...
$_SESSION['test'] = "value";
echo $_SESSION['test']; // echos "value"
```

Comment: You'll have to provide some more detail of what's not working for you, because what you've written there should work just fine - you can read and write $_SESSION like any other array.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the `session_start()` at the very beginning of the document. But it should work fine without it.

I just tested it with this file:

```php
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';
echo ($_SESSION['foo']);
```

On the very first page load, this gave me `bar` on my site.

*EDIT: Actually for me I didn't even need to specify it, it worked even without that line, directly after `session_destroy()`.*